# Arduino - PC communication

Tags: wpf, arduino, serial-port

I wrote a small wpf programm to control some LED's. I built 4 different modi:

LEDON , LEDOFF, DIMMING, FLASH

It's very simple and works fine. I send a,b,c or d (4 different buttons) to the arduino and execute the corresponding loop.

Now I try to create a slider in my WPF program that can control the LED brightness. My slider creates values from 0 to 255 which I send to the arduino.

Now I ask if the incoming byte is a number, if yes I execute a method which should determine the brightness using `analog.write(PIN,value);`.

WPF:

```
 private void targetSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            try
            {
                var val = Math.Round(targetSlider.Value).ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("WPF:  " + val);
                serialPort1.Write(val);

                var ArduVal = serialPort1.ReadByte();
                Console.WriteLine("Arduino: " + ArduVal);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Arduino:

```
void loop()
  {
    checkSerial();
    if(lightON)LightON();
    else if(lightOFF)LightOFF();
    else if(lightDIM) LightDIM();
    else if(lightBLINK) LightBLINK();
  }
  void checkSerial()
  {
    while(Serial.available()>0){
      int incoming=Serial.read();
      if(isdigit(incoming)){
        executeSlider(incoming); 
        Serial.print(incoming);
      }
      else{
          char c=incoming;
          executeCommand(c);
        }
    }
  }
   void executeSlider(int val){
        analogWrite(BLUE, val);
        analogWrite(GREEN, val);
        analogWrite(RED, val);
    }
```

As you can see, I check the values of the slider (which are sent to the arduino) and the values which arrive at the arduino.

The arduino values always commute around 50. I don't understand why? Should I pass an array? Or is something wrong with arudino-PC communication?

Console Output:

```
WPF:  2
Arduino: 53
WPF:  4
Arduino: 48
WPF:  4
Arduino: 53
WPF:  5
Arduino: 50
WPF:  6
Arduino: 53
WPF:  8
Arduino: 50
WPF:  8
Arduino: 53
WPF:  10
Arduino: 51
WPF:  10
Arduino: 53
WPF:  12
Arduino: 52
WPF:  13
Arduino: 53
WPF:  14
Arduino: 54
WPF:  14
Arduino: 53
WPF:  15
Arduino: 54
WPF:  16
Arduino: 52
WPF:  16
Arduino: 57
WPF:  17
Arduino: 52
WPF:  18
Arduino: 56
WPF:  20
Arduino: 52
WPF:  20
Arduino: 57
WPF:  21
Arduino: 52
WPF:  22
Arduino: 56
WPF:  23
Arduino: 52
WPF:  25
Arduino: 57
WPF:  26
Arduino: 53
WPF:  27
Arduino: 48
WPF:  29
Arduino: 52
WPF:  30
Arduino: 57
WPF:  31
Arduino: 53
WPF:  32
Arduino: 49
WPF:  33
Arduino: 52
WPF:  34
Arduino: 57
WPF:  35
Arduino: 53
WPF:  37
Arduino: 50
```

**EDIT:**
I changed the read function of my arduino

```
 void checkSerial()
  {
    while(Serial.available()>0){
      int incoming=Serial.read();
      if(isdigit(incoming)){
          int sliderVal=Serial.parseInt();
           executeSlider(sliderVal); 
           Serial.print(sliderVal);
      }
      else{
          char c=incoming;
          executeCommand(c);
      }
    }
  }
```

But the incoming values are still between 48-58

Comment: 48-57 are the ASCII codes of the characters 0-9. You are sending the number as a string, but interpreting each received character as an integer.

Comment: But how can I send an int. Or better, what is the best way to send values from 0-255 to the arduino?

Comment: You also have to *read* a string (up to a separator like e.g. a linefeed character), then parse it to an int.

Answer (score 0):

I thing that what you are looking for are [Serial.readStringUntil](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadStringUntil) and [Serial.parseInt()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ParseInt)

Note that parseInt() ignores any initial characters that are not digits or minus sign
Also note that it is blocking by necessity - program execution will block untill it has read the whole number(ends with a non-digit character like space or \n

You can than do something like this(just an example):

```
while(1) {
  int number = Serial.parseInt(); // Read until you find a number(sequence of digits)
  Serial.print(number); // Repeat it back
}
```

- In this case, you are ignoring the 'WPF: ' string at the begining of the line

EDIT:
What I see as strange is this:

```
WPF:  4
Arduino: 48
WPF:  4
Arduino: 53
```

Do you see the same behavior with the most recent Arduino code you are trying?
Could you try this code on your arduino and see what it reports?

```
loop() {
  while(1) { // Repeat everything back exactly without any conversions or 
    // processing on the part of arduino, byte after byte in hexa format.
    // Alternatives are DEC, HEX and OCT
    if(Serial.available()) {
      Serial.println(Serial.read(), HEX);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I write "WPF: " only in my console. I only write the value of the slider (rounded) into my serial port. Now I read the value with Serial.parseInt();. The values are still evaluated as a string.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. In that case it seems you are missing a separator between numbers sent from the PC, `serialPort1.Write(val); serialPort1.Write("\n"); ` should do the trick.
That does not seem to be the main problem however.

Answer (score 0):

your not showing all of your arduino code and it looks like your trying to get 3 values? you have no way of getting that data cause your not parsing it. look at this example if you send any command from any serial it will do this on the arduino end hope that helps.

```
   /*
    if you wanted to send 4 values.
    you could do something like "setv.1.2.3\n"
    and the data would be parsed to
    cmdv = setv;
    val  = 1;
    val2 = 2;
    val3 = 3;
    */

    String command;

    void loop()
    {
      if (Serial.available())
      {
        char c = Serial.read();
        if (c == '\n')
        {
          parseCommand(command);
          command = "";
        }
        else
        {
          // this is where it gets added
          command += c;
        }
      }
    }
    // parsed
    void parseCommand(String com)
    {
      String cmdv;
      String val;
      String val2;
      String val3;

      // set data like command.val.val2.val3
      cmdv = com.substring(0, com.indexOf("."));
      val = com.substring(com.indexOf(".")  + 2 , com.indexOf(".") + 1);
      val2 = com.substring(com.indexOf(".") + 3 , com.indexOf(".") + 2);
      val3 = com.substring(com.indexOf(".") + 4);


      if (cmdv("setv")) {
        // set values from serial "setv.1.2.3\n"
        //convert the value to int if needed val.toInt()
        // previously define color values as int
        analogWrite(BLUE, val.toInt());
        analogWrite(GREEN, val2.toInt());
        analogWrite(RED, val3.toInt());
      }

      // send values if Serial recieves "sendv.1.2.3\n"
      if (cmdv("sendv")) {
        //convert the value to int if needed val.toInt()
        Serial.println(val.toInt()); // 1
        Serial.println(val2.toInt());// 2
        Serial.println(val3.toInt());// 3
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a java application to communicate with Arduino and wanted to send PWM values to Arduino. i have used [ArduinoJson](https://arduinojson.org/) to decode the values from 0-255.you have to send JSON encoded strings to Arduino from your application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Where do you read the Arduino values you printed? WPF or Arduino Serial Monitor.
   If WPF, please read the in the serial monitor to check if its the same?
2. You use var ArduVal = serialPort1.ReadByte(); in the C# application while in the Arduino you use Serial.print(incoming);

Since you're reading bytes, then you should use Serial.write() instead of Serial.print()

3. Also, try to use Serial.ReadExisting() function from C#